# Promotinal coupon generation problem

Tags: coupon-codes

I need to create a promotional coupon for my Magento site.
From `admin> Promotions> Shopping Cart Price Rules` , I added coupon description what I need.
But when I go to the "Manage Coupon Codes" option to generate a new coupon, the block is not clickable. [image: Promotinal coupon generation problem]

Why is this happening I don't have an idea. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate coupon code by simply selecting `Specific Coupon` option under `Rule Information` tab

[image]

You can only use `Manage coupon codes` if `Use Auto Generation` option was selected in first step. If only one coupon code is required then I'll provide Voucher code and bingo. If on the other hand you want multiple (differnt) coupone codes generated then select `Use Auto Generation` and create codes under `Mange Coupone Codes`.

Comment: Hi. I need gernerate a coupon code for every logged in user to use at first time checkout. i.e if a coupon generated named "abc" , then this coupon code can be used by every logged in user for their first time ourchase.

Comment: You can limit the use of coupon to 1 time only, next time they buy and try to use coupon it won't work. Enter 1 for Uses per Customer to apply limit.

Answer (score 3):

Check `Coupon *` field in edit rule action in admin. You can find it in **General Information** tab

Coupon * should be **specific coupon** not **no coupon**

Also `Use Auto Generation` checkbox should be check.

Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your answer. When I choose "Auto Generation" it is clickable. But for my own coupon code when I didn't choose "Auto Generation" the generate coupon block is disabled.

Comment: it works. +1 for you.

Comment: Yes it will work only with Auto Generation, otherwise generate coupon block disable.